# Where is the highest point in Panau?

Tags: achievements, just-cause-2

I need to get the achievement 'Top of the World'. Where is the highest point in Panau?

Comment: Which -> Where to improve googlabilitiness?

Comment: @Stuart Doesn't Google ignore "where"? (I can't seem to make it show which words it's using in the query like it used to...)

Comment: @Matthew: Fair point. I have to admit SEO is not an area I know much about. I just thought it was more likely to match what people typed.

Comment: I thought it was the Mile High Club.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The coordinates are X: 20538 and Y: 11868. It is the top of the largest mountain.

Video walkthrough here:

Answer (score 3):

The highest point is the mountain top in the snowy region of the map.  (Want to say it's roughly in the middle, been a few months since i last played)

Comment: There's a skull not far from the peak, too.